# Restrict editing a field in TFS

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

Is it possible to restrict users from editing a field in TFS based on a user? For example suppose there is a state field and owner field. The user selected in the owner field should only be allowed to updated the state field, it should be readonly to rest of the users.

Comment: Finally, I know what's your mean.  It can be achieved, please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a rule of a field to achieve it.
Just edit the process template and make the field only editable by Admins. (You may need to install the power tools or use witexport and a good XML editor to do all the work)

```
<FIELD refname="System.Description" name="Description" type="PlainText">
        <READONLY for="[Project]\Contributors" not="[Project]\Project Collection Administrators" />
</FIELD>
```

More info from MSDN: [Apply a rule to a work item field](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404857.aspx)

---

### Restrict modification of a field to a group of users:

Use not to exclude a group from a rule. This example defines the Triage Description field as read-only for everyone except those users in the Triage Committee group.

```
<FIELD name="Triage Description">
<READONLY not="[Project]\Triage Committee" />
</FIELD>
```

---

### Update

You can also add some restriction during the transition of two state. Please see below steps and screenshot for more info.

Detail steps:

1. Open the Work Item Type from server(need tfs power pools)
2. Right click the transition select 'open details'
3. Select for or not, add the owner to a group, if you select this group. The user in this group can only be allowed to updated the state field.

[image]

Comment: I am sorry, but there is a change in my question. I have edited question with more details